# how does IdentityDbContext know my password?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

using visual studio 2013 I created an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I copied my database from the automatically created file to a server running MS SQL Server. However, when I created the connection string, all I specified was the ip address and the database name. It connects fine; I updated some data on the server and that data shows up. But how? I never told it the username or password I use to connect. Perhaps does Server Management Studio save that data somewhere that my application is apparently searching?

Comment: If you see "Integrated Security=True" in your connection string then your sql server use your windows credentials to authenticate you.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your connection string parameters?